# Python: slow for loop performance on reading, extracting and writing from a list of thousands of files

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, for-loop

I am extracting 150 different cell values from 350,000 (20kb) ascii raster files. My current code is fine for processing the 150 cell values from 100's of the ascii files, however it is very slow when running on the full data set.

I am still learning python so are there any obvious inefficiencies? or suggestions to improve the below code.

I have tried closing the 'dat' file in the 2nd function; no improvement.

```
   dat = None
```

First: I have a function which returns the row and column locations from a cartesian grid.

```
def world2Pixel(gt, x, y):
  ulX = gt[0]
  ulY = gt[3]
  xDist = gt[1]
  yDist = gt[5]
  rtnX = gt[2]
  rtnY = gt[4]
  pixel = int((x - ulX) / xDist)
  line = int((ulY - y) / xDist)
  return (pixel, line)
```

Second: A function to which I pass lists of 150 'id','x' and 'y' values in a for loop. The first function is called within and used to extract the cell value which is appended to a new list. I also have a list of files 'asc_list' and corresponding times in 'date_list'. Please ignore count / enumerate as I use this later; unless it is impeding efficiency.

```
def asc2series(id, x, y):
#count = 1
ls_id = []
ls_p = []
ls_d = []
for n, (asc,date) in enumerate(zip(asc, date_list)):
    dat = gdal.Open(asc_list)
    gt = dat.GetGeoTransform()
    pixel, line = world2Pixel(gt, east, nort)
    band = dat.GetRasterBand(1)
    #dat = None
    value = band.ReadAsArray(pixel, line, 1, 1)[0, 0]
    ls_id.append(id)
    ls_p.append(value)
    ls_d.append(date)
```

Many thanks

Comment: `dat = None` doesn't necessarily close the file. Try `dat.Close()`, or similar.

Comment: You don't appear to use `yDist`, or `rtnX`, or `rtnY`.

Comment: Your question boils down to "How do I profile Python programs" for which you should be able to find a few hits on the web.

Comment: `itertools.izip` may use less memory than `zip` with Python 2. Python3 not so much.

Comment: There's no need to `enumerate` as you don't use `n`

Comment: Like @Ulrich, my first thought "you should profile your code" and see where it's spending most of its time. This is relatively easy to do with [`cProfile` and `profile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#).

Comment: Thanks for the quick tips "peter wood". 

As for dat = None, I dont think Close() works on Gdal object http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80366/why-close-a-dataset-in-gdal-python;

I will try itertools.izip;

I use enumerate later on as in Q.

Comment: `ulX, xDist, rtnX, ulY, rtnY, yDist = gt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In world2pixel you are setting rtnX and rtnY which you don't use.
2. You probably meant `gdal.Open(asc)` -- not `asc_list`.
3. <strike>You could move `gt = dat.GetGeoTransform()` out of the loop.</strike> (Rereading made me realize you can't really.)
4. You could cache calls to `world2Pixel`.
5. You're opening dat file for each pixel -- **you should probably turn the logic around to only open files once and lookup all the pixels mapped to this file.**
6. **Benchmark, check the links in this podcast to see how:** http://talkpython.fm/episodes/show/28/making-python-fast-profiling-python-code

Comment: Point 5 and 6 should be in bold..  :-) replace could with should. re-processing a file is generally bad.